# django Form, MultipleChoiceField and circular import

Tags: django, django-forms, wagtail

I try to setup a ModelForm Formset - with Checkbox fields...

But if I set a queryset for my MultipleChoiceField I get an "ImportError"

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Event' from partially initialized module 'ferienspiel.event.models' (most likely due to a circular import)`

How can I make a queryset for my MultipleChoiceField-Fields in `forms.py? to avoid a circular import Error?

This
`self.fields["event"].queryset = Event.objects.all()` is the reason for the ImportError. How can I populate my Checkboxes with Events-data with an other way?

My setup:

```
- app
--- model.py (contains Model and Formhandler, for Wagtail Page `def serve()` )
--- form.py (formset setup)
--- ulrs.py
--- views.py
```

forms.py

```
class ChildForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(ChildForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["event"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["event"].queryset = Event.objects.all().order_by("date", "time")

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "date_of_birth", "text")
        widgets = {
       ...
       ...
```

model.py

```
class Event(Page):
    location = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=False)
    time = models.TimeField(null=False)


class EventRegistrationPage(Page):
    intro = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def serve(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            parent_form = ParentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            childs_form = ChildFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

            if all([parent_form.is_valid(), childs_form.is_valid()]):
                for child in childs_form:
                    # print(f"child {child.cleaned_data}")
                    if child.is_valid():
                        new_child = child.save(commit=False)
                        new_child.parent = new_parent
                        new_child.save()
                        new_child.event.set(
                            child.cleaned_data.get("event")
                        )
                        child.save_m2m()
                        childs_data.append(new_child)
```

Comment: Just a tip: since this is a problem with imports, it would be helpful to include the actual `import` lines as part of your code snippet, so that there's less guesswork for us to do.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, circular imports are the result of bad designs, you should find a better method, but if you want to stick with this, you can do it like so:-

```py
from . import forms # if the form is not in same app change . to the app_name

parent_form = forms.ParentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
childs_form = forms.ChildFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

forms.py

```py
from . import models

self.fields["event"].queryset = models.Event.objects.all().order_by("date", "time")
```

This should resolve the circular import

Comment: Yes, I know that - but I have no clue for another better way. And I think this ```self.fields["event"].queryset = Event.objects.all().order_by("date", "time")``` is the reason for the ImportError...

Comment: have you tried the above code?

Comment: Yes, but It changes nothing

Answer (score 0):

Move the import line that imports the forms module into the body of the `serve` method. That way, it only has to import that module when running the `serve` method, rather than at startup:

```
class EventRegistrationPage(Page):
    intro = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def serve(self, request):
        from ferienspiel.events.forms import ParentForm, ChildFormSet

        if request.method == "POST":
            parent_form = ParentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            childs_form = ChildFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
```